# Getting HTTP 500 when trying to log in using cookie authentication with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, cookie-authentication

**ASP.NET Core 2.2**

I've wrestled with this problem for a long time...

Whenever I'm trying to anything related to logging in or out through HttpContext I get a HTTP 500 error.

I've scaffolded the identity and done the changes I needed, so I'm more or less using the microsofts GitHub code one-to-one.

---

The actions I'm doing get done (logging in/out, changing password) **BUT** the **`RedirectToPage()`** call just returns a HTTP 500 error.

I suspect it has to do something with reloading too quickly and not waiting for the HttpContext to login or authenticate?

I've managed to make the Logging in work by instead of `RedirectToPage()` using `Response.Redirect(returnUrl)`

Here's my `Startup.cs`

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add httpcontext service
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        // Services identity depends on
        services.AddScoped<IIdentityRepository, IdentityRepository>();
        //services.AddOptions().AddLogging();

        // Services used by identity
        services.AddScoped<IUserStore, UserStore>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserValidator, UserValidator>();
        services.AddScoped<IPasswordValidator, PasswordValidator>();
        services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher, PasswordHasher>();
        services.AddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
        // No interface for the error describer so we can add errors without rev'ing the interface
        services.AddTransient<IdentityErrorDescriber>();
        services.AddScoped<UserManager>();
        services.AddScoped<SignInManager>();

        // Identity cookie paths
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(o =>
            {
                o.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
                o.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
                o.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            });


        // Require authorization on every page by default
        // Allow areas and add an area to path
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.AllowAreas = true;
                options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("App", "/summary", "");
            });

        services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

The razor page example for Changing password as well:
(After correctly typing the right old password and a new one I get a HTTP 500 error)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync () {
if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
    return Page ();
}

var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync (User);
if (user == null) {
    return NotFound ($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
}

var changePasswordResult = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync (user, Input.OldPassword, Input.NewPassword);
if (!changePasswordResult.Succeeded) {
    foreach (var error in changePasswordResult.Errors) {
        ModelState.AddModelError (string.Empty, error.Description);
    }
    return Page ();
}

await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync (user);
//_logger.LogInformation("User changed their password successfully.");
StatusMessage = "Your password has been changed.";

return RedirectToPage(); // THIS PROBABLY CAUSING THE HTTP 500
```

}

Comment: Can you check your ASP.NET Core *server logs*? An error 500 usually means that there is an unhandled exception on the server side, and that should be automatically logged by the framework. So by looking at the logs, you should be able to get some more information about what *exactly* is going wrong there.

Comment: IISExpress is just logging the requests, nothing more there and .Net Core itself should display any errors since UseDeveloperExceptionPage() is enabled.

Comment: If you run the application through Visual Studio with IISExpress, you should see the actual ASP.NET Core server logs in the Output panel when you select “ASP.NET Core server” in the dropdown.

Comment: @poke THANK YOU for that! I never knew it printed the IISExpress errors. Found my problem and everything works now. **In this case** the problem was that my Dispose method in the UserManager class threw a not yet implemented. It's weird that it would not display the error message? Any idea what could cause that? Also it shows the log when you Debug under the Debug dropdown option, there's no "ASP.NET Core server" in the dropdown.

Comment: It’s not IISExpress errors nor is it an IISExpress log. It’s the ASP.NET Core application logs. IISExpress (and ISS too) don’t do much but just forward the requests to the Kestrel server that runs your ASP.NET Core application. That’s why you have a separate log from your application. If you run your application directly (without IISExpress), you will also see the log output in the console by default. And there should be a drop down value called “YourApplication - ASP.NET Core Web Server” but yeah, it also appears in the Debug output.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my answer. Feel free to clarify in the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke) I got the answer.

> The exceptions not shown when getting a 500 error in the browser will be displayed in Visual Studios Output window when you Debug your app.

My specific problem was in a Dispose method throwing **not yet implemented** in the User Store class.